# Harism android Page Curl

Tags: android, animation, page-curl

I am using [harism android page curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl).It works brilliantly. My app works in landscape mode and I want to start with an open book.
As I am working in landscape mode the framework automatically set

> SHOW_TWO_PAGES

property.

Now when the app begins on right side I can see PAGE0.PNG, which is my first page of the book, and on left side its blank space.

**Instead I want PAGE0.PNG on left hand side and PAGE1.PNG on right hand side.** How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure but if will try to call `setCurrentIndex(1)` from https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/blob/master/src/fi/harism/curl/CurlView.java. But this probably won't solve your issue completely since user can try to flip back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding, `mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(1);` to the `SizeChangedObserver` class in the **CurlActivity**.

See this,

```
private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
        if (w > h) {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
            mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
            mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(1);  //--- Add this line.. 
        } else {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
            mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
        }
    }
}
```